# lift adobe premiere ram allocation limit?

Tags: premiere

I am working on my fight premiere video. I do have a really expensive high end computer. First I only used 16 gb of ram and when it would use the 16gb adobe would freeze and it would kind of get stuck. Now I plugged in 32 additional gigs and I have 48 gigs of ram. However my computer isn't using more then 31 GB. At first I had issues because the standby ram wasn't being reduced and there would be no free ram. I downloaded microsoft's utility to free stanby ram.  Now I have 17 gigs free. [image]

It still refuses to allocate more ram to premiere. 
Is this because premiere isn't used to have 48 gigs? can I lift this ram cap somewhere?

it hits a ceiling of 31 gigs of ram and refuses to allocate further.

[image: http://i.gyazo.com/6bdcbbd7535a6ffede9002d824b9e164.png]

---

I upgraded from premiere cs6 to 2014.1 cc pro and pro started using almost all the ram at times. However that didn't solve issues for me.

Comment: Have you checked to see if your motherboard actually supports more than 32GB of RAM? And What version of windows are you running, some of them might be limited in memory support.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a Premiere issue, but an issue with your PC. As Andrew said, you may not actually be able to use more than 32Gb.

Comment: Just for the records, probably the problem is not that one, but, have you tried to run a full memtest ? Download Memtest+ 5.01 from http://www.memtest.org/#downiso , burn it on a cd and run the test until you have at least one pass working. Said this at least we can put aside a motherboard/ram problem in accessing all the 48 Gigs ;) and go check more in deep for the resolution.

Answer (score 2):

Premiere does not have a maximum memory usability limit. As several others pointed out, this is probably a motherboard limitation issue. @nofare's solution for working with proxies is one way to reduce the memory needs for your project.

My guess would be, based on your original statement, that the problem is not memory allocation, but disk read speed or perhaps some overly-gargantuan source files. I edit HD and 4K in Premiere on a MBP with 16GB ram all the time and can't ever remember maxing out my RAM.

A few other things to check, assuming for the sake of argument that your motherboard is not the problem:

- What is Premiere's internal ["soft" maximum memory allocation](https://www.digitalrebellion.com/blog/posts/premiere_pro_memory_settings_explained) set to? This will not only tell you how much your OS is actually seeing, but also how much Premiere is willing to consume.
- Where are your source files located - on internal storage, a USB drive, in the cloud, etc? Premiere could be slowing down as a result of trying to read your source files, particularly if you are using multiple streams simultaneously, from slow I/O sources like USB 2.0 or cloud-based drives.
- What is your largest-resolution timeline asset? And, how is it encoded? If you're using gigantic Photoshop files on your timeline, yeah, well...it's gonna be slow. Same goes for RAW video or even 4k mpeg files. They just don't edit easily and could contribute to choppiness or temporary "freezing" in the interface.
- What is your [playback display quality](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/source-monitor-program-monitor.html#sourcemonitorandprogrammonitoroverview) set to? I typically work with this set to 1/2 or even 1/4 for optimum fps.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using proxies instead of editing native files.

- Transcode your native files to lighter versions, by for example using the ProRes Proxy codec, or the DNxHD36 codec. You'll end up with lower resolution files, but they'll be "lighter" (less large/heavy) and therefore easier for your computer to read/play.
- The proxy files and the native files should have the same names. Keep it as such. So for instance, a native file called "Car.mov" (shot in ProRes HQ) would have its proxy version also called "Car.mov", but in ProRes Proxy. Same with, say, RED camera files: a native R3D file folder would be "D009_C002_0621AJ.RDC" and its proxy version, say in ProRes Proxy, would be "D009_C002_0621AJ.mov".
- Import those proxy files to your editing project. Edit normally.
- Once you picture-lock, unlink your edit from the Proxy files. Then link your edit to your native files. Because the proxy files and the native files have the same name, you should have no issue doing the relinking.
- Presto, you'll then have a picture-locked edit with native files. Do you color correction, and export.

Here's a simple how-to video that explains the unlinking/relinking: https://youtu.be/hsqFilCBKIY
It's for Premiere CS6. There are other how-tos out there for other editing programs.

Comment: This may provide a work around for the issue, but would be better if you could expand it with more details on how to use this feature to solve the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

I still run CS6, but it shouldnt matter. My system has 128 GB of ram, and premiere takes full advantage of all of it. There is a setting in After Effects where you can allocate how many cores (in my case 48 cores), and I am able to do 3GB per core using 40 cores and I leave 8 cores with 8 gb of ram for overhead.

You could look into a program called ProcessLasso, it is fantastic for managing and moving around, allocating system processes, such as memory trimming, realtime throttling (so your computer doesnt hang), priorities of memory, pinning cores to specific programs, etc.

It speeds things up- tremendously. Especially if you have a lot of cores and a lot of ram.